# Why is it so hard to build a mobile OS?

Tags: windows-mobile, mobile, symbian

I'm wondering what makes it so hard for companies to be on time when delivering mobile software? I partly understand why it takes time to shell out a first version of an OS (you have to take care of all the low level stuff), but once you have all the APIs in place, why does it take months to deliver simple UI iterations (like copy&paste in case of Windows Phone 7). Why do Symbian UI updates take so long? I'm not familiar with Android.
Especially in the case of Meego & Bada which already base on Linux, I have trouble understanding how it can take > 1 year to simply make a running product. I'm sure there are good reasons, I don't want to be ignorant, that's why I'm asking.
Is it maybe because performance is very hard to achieve? I'm not sure, but my experience with doing "low level" DirectX API stuff is, that it's fairly easy to achieve fast 2D graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because writing (good or bad) software is hard. I think you are trivializing how much work actually goes into these projects. I'm not trying to be critical, but I think you just haven't tried to deliver a large project on time, on budget, and to specification, nor do you have a real understanding of the complexities of the features you pan off as simple.

For academic exercise, try re-implementing cut-n-paste across every windows control without using the OS hooks. Now make it work with office content, or images, or any other advanced content